# Defining Lands that are not deserts

Tags: data, terminology

I need to know what we call the lands that are not pure deserts that i can think that they are the areas of metropolitan areas plus rular areas or forests plus areas that are near freshwater that can be occupied by people with minimum efforts.

Are there any information for this for countries?

Comment: A desert is any area that has on average less than 250 mm of rainfall per year, it has nothing to do with land use, or land cover, so you just need to find some average rainfall dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For Free GIS data, there is quite lots of resources. You may check below link that contains reference for all GIS data (land, forest etc..). Check references under **Administrative Boundaries** in same page.

**Reference:**
https://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/

Comment: If someone downvote, please correct me if I am wrong.